# how to create citext columns with liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I've got a postgresql database that is created from liquibase. How can I configure liquibase to create CITEXT columns?

I ran across this URL but unsure where to put this configuration. I'm using version 3.3.2.

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1234

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) is the documentation on how to use parameters in liquibase (which the bug ticket you posted refers to). What happens if you try to set this? Does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the changelog file. You didn't specify what format your changelog is in, so this assumes XML, but the instructions are similar for other formats.

Basically, if you have a column that should be CITEXT, you can use that type in the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
    <changeSet author="Pete" id="1430490076262-3216" objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS">
        <createTable tableName="AA_BUILD">
            <column name="STAGE" type="NUMBER">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="ITERATION" type="NUMBER">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="BUILD_NUM" type="NUMBER">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="CHANGED_IN_DEV_DT" type="date"/>
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" type="CITEXT"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```